# How do you add to the value of a Python dictionary key if its within a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been using python (program is PyCharm) for a little while now and I don't know ALL of python so the answer might be staring at me in the face.

So I have multiple dictionaries, most contained within the same class as shown:

```
class Store(object):
    storage = {
        'Console CDs': 3,
        'Computer CDs': 5,
        'CD cases': 10,
        'Game cartridges': 3,
        'Cartridge Cases': 5,
        'Xcubes': 0,
        'GS1s': 0,
        'CSs': 0
    }
    prices = {
        'Console Game': 30.00,
        'PC Game': 30.00,
        'CS Game': 25.00,
        'Xcubes': 250.00,
        'GS1s': 250.00,
        'CSs': 150.00
```

And then, I have a function for shopping in a catalog I made (in which catalog is ALSO a dictionary in the class `Store`. The part I am stuck on is:

```
for key in Store.catalog:
    if key == x:
        z = input("How many?\n")
            if profit >= float(z) * Store.catalog[key]:
                y = input("Are you sure? This will cost you " + str(Store.catalog[key]) + " cash. Enter Yes or "
                                                                                              "No.\n")
                if y.lower() == "yes":
                    profit -= float(z) * Store.catalog[key]
                    print("Current Money: $" + str(profit))
                    print("Purchase Successful.")
                    for item in Store.storage:
                        if x == item:
                            Store.storage[item].update({int(z)})
                    time.sleep(1)
                    main_function()
                elif y.lower() == "no":
                    print("Purchase Canceled.")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    shopping()
```

Pinpointing the `for item in Store.storage loop`, I want to add however many of a certain item the user buys from the catalog to their storage if they successfully purchase the item(s).
The problem is that if I write it as
`Store.storage[item].update({int(z)})`
it does not detect the
`.update`
syntax. However, if I do it without defining the class,
`storage[item].update({int(z)})`,
it does not detect the `storage` dictionary.

Is there something wrong with my code, or is it because I made the dictionaries in a class? Should I delete the class?

Comment: why do you expect `Store.storage[item].update(...)` to work, when `storage[item]` returns an integer? The problem isn't that your dictionaries are in a class (although, that seems pointless - just make them module-level variables), it's that you don't quite understand how to use a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, I still have some work to do with learning Python. However, I didn't expect `Store.storage[item].update(...)` to work, I was just trying to see if it was possible to use it in this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: My point is, that all the issue with classes (and especially Pycharm, which isn't really a relevant tag for this question) have nothing to do with your error. Your error would *still happen* if there were no classes involved, and everything was happening in the global scope.

Comment: Which, by the way, is why you should be providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. If you had taken the time to produce that, it would have become obvious that the problem isn't your class.

Answer (score 2):

You either do:
 `Store.storage.update({item:int(z)})`
or do:
 `Store.storage[item] = int(z)`